# How to see whether a vector is empty in R

Tags: r

First of all, I need to initialize an empty vector in R,
Does the following work ?

```
vec <- vector()
```

And how I can evaluate whether vec is empty or not ?

Comment: Have you tried running `vec <- vector()` to see what it does?

Comment: Try `str(vec)` and `length(vec)`. Also, make sure you understand the implications of `vector()`'s `mode` argument and its default value.

Answer (score 24):

It seems that using length(vector_object) works:

```
vector.is.empty <- function(x) return(length(x) ==0 )

> v <- vector()
> class(v)
[1] "logical"
> length(v)
[1] 0
> vector.is.empty(v)
[1] TRUE
> 
> vector.is.empty(c())
[1] TRUE
> vector.is.empty(c(1)[-1])
[1] TRUE
```

Please tell if there is any case not covered.

Comment: while this also returns `TRUE` also for e.g. `NULL` (as @RAndres pointed out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73507844/1870254) and `data.frame()` this is usually desirable (follows the [pythonic] [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) strategy, which yields flexible code). According you want to avoid the exact solution: `is.vector(x) & !length(x)` and instead consider naming the function `is.empty` instead of `vector.is.empty`.

Answer (score 3):

From the help file of `vector`:

> `vector` produces a vector of the given length and mode.
> ...
>
> #### Usage
>
> `vector(mode = "logical", length = 0)`

If you run the code, `vec <- vector()` and evaluate it, `vec`, returns `logical(0)`. A logical vector of size 0. This makes sense, seeing as how the default arguments for the `vector` function is `vector(mode="logical", length=0)`.

If you check `length(vec)`, we know the length of our vector is also 0, meaning that our vector, `vec`, is empty.

If you want to create other types of vectors that are not of type `logical`, you can also read the help file of `vector` using `?vector`. You will find that `vector(mode='character')` will make an empty character vector, `vector(mode='integer')` will make an empty integer vector, and so on.

You can also create empty vectors by calling the names of the other "atomic modes", as the help file calls them:

`character()`, `integer()`, `numeric()`/`double()`, `complex()`, `character()`, and `raw()`.

Answer (score 3):

The `NULL` case is not covered in the excellent example of @yu-shen. Sometimes it is not the same to have a NULL object and length-zero object. The function below cover those cases.
Best,

```r
is_empty <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) == 0 & !is.null(x)) {
    TRUE
  } else {
    FALSE
  }
}

x <- vector()
is_empty(x)
#> [1] TRUE

y <- NULL
length(y)
#> [1] 0
is_empty(y)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately base R does not provide an `is.empty` function. You can implement one yourself:

```r
is.empty <- function(x) length(x)==0
```

Or use [`rlang::is_emtpy`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/is_empty.html). But `if(length(x)==0)` will be understood just as well.

If for some unlikely reason you need to be sure that you are dealing with a "`vector`" you need to check that in addition with `is.vector`.